# Can not get any results with return (x), how to extract function result?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, return

Dear StackOverflow community, I'm new at coding and I've been trying to work with R for my P.hD. thesis.
This is the first function that I wrote and it seems to not return(x) the final result.

```
import_variable_N_columns <- function(x) {
  if (ncol(x) > 3) {
    x <- x[c(1, 2, 3)]
    return(x)
  }
}
import_variable_N_columns(lh_pial_surfarea_1)
```

The result also have 4 columns, and I want just the first three. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you,
Fernanda

Comment: put the `return(x)` outside the `if` clause

Comment: If that functionality is all that you need, you can simply use `import_variable_N_columns <- function(x) utils:::head.default(x, n=3)` or `import_variable_N_columns <- function(x) x[seq_len(min(3,ncol(x)))]`.

Comment: @BenBolker thank you! Just tried like this import_variable_N_columns <- 
    function(x) {
      if (ncol(x) > 3) {
        x <- x[c(1, 2, 3)]
      } 
      return(x)
    } 
but it keeps returnig 4 columns

Comment: @r2evans thank you very much, but it didn't work either :(

Comment: It is weird because it prints the right result, but didn't change the variable number of columns

Comment: Fernanda, *"it didn't work"* doesn't help, as we don't know ***how*** it did not work. What do you mean by *"didn't change the variable"* ... are you expecting it to change the dimensions of the variable you provided as an argument? If so, I suggest you read about the difference between "side-effect" and "functional programming". (Hint: try `x <- import_variable_N_columns(x)`, if I'm right.)

Comment: Thank you @r2evans! As a beginner, I still don't know to express my self in "code language", but I hope to get better and better with time. Actually your last hint was the solution, thank you again

Comment: Expressing your needs in ways that are easily interpreted by other programmers is an art that takes time to refine, no worries. I will repeat that it might be beneficial to brush up on "side-effect" and avoiding it; one good reference is http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#return-values, though wikipedia and Google will also present generic non-R discussions about it as well.